# Using Merge in Oracle to update a table and clear out a field if the record is not in the source table

Tags: oracle, merge

I need some help converting an MSSQL Merge statement into Oracle

```
MERGE INTO A
      USING B on a.a_id = b.b_id
WHEN MATCHED and isNull(a.a_field, '') <> isNull(b.b_field,'') THEN
  UPDATE SET a.a_field = b.b_field
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
  INSERT (a_id, a_field)
  VALUES (b.b_id, b.b_field)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  UPDATE SET a.a_field = ''
```

I've been able to get the conversion to this point

```
MERGE INTO A
      USING B on a.a_id = b.b_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a.a_field = b.b_field
  WHERE nvl(a.a_field, '') <> nvl(b.b_field,'')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (a.a_id, a.a_field)
  VALUES (b.b_id, b.b_field)
```

I don't know how to setup the merge statement so that it will clear out a.a_field when there is no record for that same a.a_id in the B table.